# I'm looking for a way to bulk WhatsApp Web messages using programming via websites, apps, or programs

Tags: javascript, web, message, whatsapp, bulk

Is there a way to manipulate WhatsApp Web so I can send messages through a program, using JavaScript by example, or any other method. My plan is to use a database of phone numbers saved in my phone, so I can filter out contacts and send massive messages via WhatsApp Web.

Comment: Surely there's enough spam on the internet already?

Comment: You are looking for paid services such as [Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp)

Answer (score 1):

I would check [Whatsapp Business API](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api), if you're not doing it for a business endeavor I think it's going to be pretty hard, since it's against their term of service.

Comment: If you liked this answer please select it, you just need to accept it (right under the upvote/downvote button)